# Is there a way to make click-and-drag sliding to resize the extent of a Blender area easy?

Tags: interface

I often have trouble accurately grabbing the boundary between Blender Editor sub-areas in order to drag-resize it (or in order to merge it with an adjacent subarea). That is, I have trouble grabbing the 'pane'-like separator between two distinct editor sub-areas, as in this example:

[image]

After a few repeated attempts, I can typically grab it and resize/merge as needed, but for an action I perform at least dozens of time per Blendering session, it'd be nice to make it somewhat more comfortable to easily do. Is there maybe a keyboard shortcut for "resize area towads the left/right/top/bottom", or a UI element I can edit to make the 'separator' slightly larger for easy click-dragging?

Comment: If there is an answer to this, I'd really like to know - This has been the bane of my blender existence for years.